# uncaught exception: INVALID_TOKEN | (intermediate value).forEach is not a function with AJAX response(JSON format)

Tags: json, ajax, twilio-php

I am getting error `uncaught exception: INVALID_TOKEN (intermediate value).forEach is not a function`

My code is:

```
$('#start')
    .on('click', function() {
        $.getJSON('/twillio-new/token.php', {
            name: $('#my-name')
                .val(),
            identity: $('#my-identity')
                .val()
        }, function(data) {
            // Create the endpoint, and then initialize the main calling app
            var endpoint = new Twilio.Endpoint(data.token);
            $('#startDiv')
                .hide();
            $('#callDiv')
                .show();
            init(endpoint);
        });
    });
```

JSON Response:

> {"name":"cool
>   room","identity":"test","token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImN0eSI6InR3aWxpby1mcGE7dj0xIn0.eyJqdGkiOiJlMWE3NTI4YzYyMzdiMGE0MmZlYTc0NDk2MjRlOTFiNC0xNTA3MjEwNjQyIiwiaXNzIjoiZTFhNzUyOGM2MjM3YjBhNDJmZWE3NDQ5NjI0ZTkxYjQiLCJzdWIiOiJBQzVlMTVhMDg5NjVkNWRjM2ZkOWI3YmNiOGMyM2FhMjgxIiwiZXhwIjoxNTA3MjE0MjQyLCJncmFudHMiOnsiaWRlbnRpdHkiOiJ0ZXN0IiwidmlkZW8iOnsicm9vbSI6IiRuYW1lIn19fQ.pvfGEoVripcjq588p8l3QixuVJ4sHBjMdmWa8tspTtY"}

I am generating and getting access token for Twilio Video calling api using this. Please let me know what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which SDK do you have installed? I have seen this error when the code being used was for the incorrect SDK. Looks like the code you are using is for the version 5. Do you have version 5 installed? There have been numerous version based issues with Twilio

Comment: Twilio SDK version is 5.15.1 that I am using. Any issue with this version? Any suggestion?

Comment: That should be the newest version. Can you post part of the code that lists the actual .foreach function? You also might be incorrectly importing the module which would mean the function would not be recognized because of that. I have had that issue before too.

Comment: I am using code from here https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/05/getting-started-with-twilio-video.html. But I am generating Access token using PHP like this http://prntscr.com/gub7rs. This is the only difference. But in this article its mentioned that we can generate token using PHP.

Comment: https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/video-access-token-server-php https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/user-identity-access-tokens#php Your code is too old, it is a versioning issue. That is from 2015 and the old sdk, they are not compatible. That is your problem.

Comment: But the SDK and the code of generate Access token is latest. I am just using HTML/JS from that article. So you mean this is the issue?

Comment: Yes. This is the issue. The .forEach is a javascript function which was my biggest clue and when I first asked you about versioning issues. Go check out the twilio documentation. They provide examples and they are decent. I answered your question my friend

Comment: <script src="//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/v1/twilio-video.min.js"></script> thats the new one on the twilio site. You were using http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/conversations/v0.7/js/releases/0.7.1.b1-7238b35/twilio-conversations-loader.min.js version . The old one.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/download-video-sdks#javascript-sdk This is what you are looking for to get started the video sdk. The link you just posted is from that page.